# take :first elem img src content and pop 2nd elem bg-img property (featured img in WP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have external RSS feeds populating the below reoccurring class `elements`.

```
<div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div>
<div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div>
<div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div>
```

I want to simply take the `:first` instance which is also latest from feed; take it's `img src` contents and use that `img src` to populate my second element, which is: '`.post-thumbnail`' css `background-image:` property.

So, basically I want my element `.post-thumbnail`'s `background-image:` property to populate from the first instance of `.featimg` child `<img src="">` content.

**Note: My `.post-thumbail` is the element where my 'Wordpress featured image' attaches to background-image.**

I have the below script thus far -- but for some reason this isn't working, and it's not pulling in that image to be *featured image* *ie.* `.post-thumbnail`

```
var getImageSrc = $('.featimg img').attr('src'); // .featimg img is correct selector
$('.site-featured-content').css('background-image', 'url(' + getImageSrc + ')');
```

Comment: The curly braces are irrelevant in you html. Post the fully rendered markup. This seems to be a question about appropriately using jquery to do dom manipulation. Please give us the rendered content.

Comment: Thanks... It just renders an image. <img src="">, sorry I thought I made that apparent later in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to limit the image selector to the first element in the array and use the .post-thumbnail selector in the second line of your code:

```
var getImageSrc = $('.featimg img').first().attr('src');
$('.post-thumbnail').css('background-image', 'url(' + getImageSrc + ')');
```

This should give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks so this appears to solve the first part of the question, albeit not the second. As it's still not attaching, maybe it's the Wordpress CMS context.

Comment: It seems you have an error either in your question or the second part of your code - you keep mentioning you want to set the background property of the '.post-thumbnail element', but your code is trying to set the property for  the '.site-featured-content' element - change that and it might work.